# Using tf.trainable_variables() to show names of trainable variables

Tags: tensorflow

I'm dealing with *weights* in a `RNNCell`.

I have the following code

```
var_names = []    
for var in tf.trainable_variables():    
    var_names.append(var.name)
```

In another file called `model.py`, I am printing the names of the trainable variables just appended to `var_names`. However, I find that the "name" attribute of the trainable variables is not useful because not very descriptive.

Do the weights of an `RNNcell` have names?

If that's useful, here's another possibly relevant piece of code:

```
cell_fn = tf.nn.rnn_cell.GRUCell   
rnn_fw_1 = cell_fn(num_hidden_1, **additional_cell_args)    
rnn_fw_1 = tf.nn.rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper(rnn_fw_1, input_keep_prob=keep_prob_1)
```

Comment: Please apply the code tag to your post to make seeing code easier.

Answer (score 20):

Try this:

```
variables_names = [v.name for v in tf.trainable_variables()]
values = sess.run(variables_names)
for k, v in zip(variables_names, values):
    print "Variable: ", k
    print "Shape: ", v.shape
    print v
```

Comment: Thank you. I have solved this problem. The problem is caused because the model.py and train.py are two files. I integrate them into one file and it works.