# Ground pretrained embedding while learning embedding for new words in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, word2vec

I tried using the following code snippet. Grounding the pretrained embeddings and learning embeddings only for the new vocab. But the embeddings for the predefined words also got changed.

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hmmm, looks like you did things right. Print the collection of trainable variables and let us know if `embs_pretrained` is still in there or not. The default behavior of the optimizer should be to only update variables that are in this collection. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41951657/using-tf-trainable-variables-to-show-names-of-trainable-variables

Comment: Variable: embs_only_in_train:0
Shape: (2787110, 100)

Variable: weights/Variable:0
Shape: (2998523, 100)

Variable: biases/Variable:0
Shape: (2998523,)

Comment: So what you've just validated is that `embs_pretrained` is NOT in the TRAINABLE_VARIABLES collection. Yet, that variable IS being changed by the optimizer? This should be impossible. The default behavior of the optimizer is to update only the TRAINABLE_VARIABLES. The optimizer's `minimize` function also has a property `var_list` which allows you to explicitly pass the variables you want to be updated (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Optimizer#minimize). You could do that as well, though that should be redundant if `embs_pretrained` isn't trainable already.

Comment: hmm. I'll edit and update the code above for you to have a look. I might have done some mistake in later steps. Moreover, I even tried changing both "embs_pretrained" and "embs_only in_train" to trainable = False. The loss as the end of each iteration still continues to reduce, which is absurd.

Comment: `trainable=False` should have been all you need. Perplexing.

Comment: @DavidParks Can you have a look now. I have updated the code.

Comment: You should post the code in text format, not an image.

Comment: Had to post it as an image to preserve the formatting.

Comment: Could you try isolating the non-trainable update issue into a minimal example (and then use text + indentation to get a code block rather than an image)? Lots going on in those screenshots.

Comment: Got it fixed, the embeddings were normalized in an intermediate step which is not the case with traditional skipgram implementation.